# ARDL non-stationary

Tags: stationarity, autoregressive, ardl

I have multiple explanatory variables and one dependent variable.
Data for all are collected at an annual basis, time series, dependent on their t-1 value.
¨
Will use of ARDL Autoregressive distributed lag be appropritate to apply?

If so, some other questions regarding ARDL:
Do all, both Xs and Y, need to be I(1)? or is it ok if some Xs are I(0)?
I also did read somewhere that for ARDL non-stationary data can be used?
If have non-stationary data and have to turn it stationary, is it right that I can use either 1 differencing OR just include time as an independent variable?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi: that's a lmyth that an ARDL requires stationarity. It doesn't. But you still need both sides of the model to be integrated of the same order.  There are some good political science papers on the ARDL. Either look at some questions I've answered in the past or anything in the literature by Keele or Deboef ( could be spelled wrong ). Let me see if I can find one of what I'm talking about. If I find it, I'll send a link.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't blndly  just use 8 explanatory variables. It's better to see what  variables look meaningful first. The ARDL is best understood with the use of one.

Comment: Here's one. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-5907.2007.00307.x Let me see if I can find one more where the ARDL subtleties are dealt with. Note that there should be a free one on the internet. The above link was meant to just gives the paper details.

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for and I haven't read it but it looks useful and the references in the back of it, particularly the one by Enns and Wlezien, might be helpful. https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/42958EF08A89712501ECF320FE2A6327/S2049847021000315a.pdf/how-to-avoid-incorrect-inferences-while-gaining-correct-ones-in-dynamic-models.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! 
When you say " the ARDL is best understood with the use of one", do you mean that it is best to have only one explanatory variable?

Comment: I just mean that, when starting out, it's best to look at the relation between two variables because it could be that a lot of the independent variables are insignficant in your model. Note that testing for significance in an ARDL depends critically on whether one assumes that the variables are cointegrated. So, using eight variables right away could definitely lead to mis-leading results.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand:)